# what's the difference between include ":projName" and include "projName" in gradle 's settings.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I see a settings.gralde in an android project like this,

```
include ':progressfragment', 'progressfragment-native'
```

what's the difference between `include ":projName"` and `include "projName"` in gradle 's settings.gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good question.

`include "project"` and `include ":project"` are the same in the instance as they are pointing to a project in the same directory.

You can use `include ":parentproject:project"` or `include ":project:subproject"` to specify levels of projects.

Look at section 57.7 on the official Gradle docs for one of their examples: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html.

Comment: Did this help you understand?